# How can I call a member from a templated base class on a templated derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, token-name-resolution

With this setup:

```
template<int N>
struct Base {
    void foo();
};

class Derived : Base<1> {
    static void bar(Derived *d) {
        //No syntax errors here
        d->Base<1>::foo();
    }
};
```

Everything works fine. However, with this example:

```
template<class E>
struct Base {
    void foo();
};

template<class E>
class Derived : Base<E> {
    static void bar(Derived<E> *d) {
        //syntax errors here
        d->Base<E>::foo();
    }
};
```

I get:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
error: '::foo' has not been declared
```

What's the difference? Why does the second cause a syntax error?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Darn, typo. This question is garbage.

Answer (score 1):

With the premise that your code compiles fine on Clang 3.2 (see [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3COedR%2415)) and GCC 4.7.2 (see [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3COedR%2416)), I do not see a reason for using `Base<E>::`: just use `d->foo()`:

```
template<class E>
struct Base {
    void foo() { }
};

template<class E>
struct Derived : Base<E> {
    static void bar(Derived<E> *d) {
        //syntax errors here
        d->foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> d;
    Derived<int>::bar(&d);
}
```

Alternatively, you could try using the `template` disambiguator:

```
d->template Base<E>::foo();
```